# Passing NSString Between ViewControllers Returning NULL

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to pass an NSString from one View Controller to another. Although its a pretty easy thing to do but i don't know what i am doing wrong which is resulting in null received data. Here is the simplified code:

**DetailViewController.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cUrlString;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
@synthesize cUrlString;
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"URL COMMENT STRING %@", cUrlString);
}
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        WebViewController *wvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewControllerNew"];
        TheItem *entry = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        wvc.title = entry.title;
        wvc.urlString = entry.link;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];

        DetailViewController *cvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        cvc.cUrlString = entry.link;
        //WHEN I USE NSLOG Below, it gives me the correct URL HERE
        NSLog(@"ENTRY LINK %@", cvc.cUrlString);  

    }
```

I have given a simplified version of the code. Also see that the NSLog statement in FirstViewController.m shows the correct data in it but the log in the viewDidLoad method of DetailViewController.m shows null. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me, let's non simplified version?

Comment: where r u pushing the detail viewcontroller from firstviewcontroller? show that code

Comment: Are you calling self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath of tableview. And try with writing cvc.cUrlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entry.link];

Comment: Is entry.link non empty?

Comment: So the issue is that entry.link is null and it passes its nil value to cvc.cUrlString

Comment: @NikosM. sorry, my fault. entry.link is not null as i have said in the question.

Comment: Please check your are allocating one viewC.And pushing another viewC.I mean different instance of same class..

Comment: can you tell me what is wvc?

Comment: @AkshayNalawade its an instance of another class where i am also pushing some data

Comment: @AJ112 You should access the property as `self.cUrlString` inside your `DetailViewController`.

Comment: @Amar already tried that. didn't work

Comment: @AJ112 Something seems to be fundamentally wrong. If your are not pushing or presenting the `cvc` instance, the `viewDidLoad` should not be called for it, since the `view` for the controller will not be created. Are `cvc` and `wvc` are instances of different class or `DetailViewController`?

Comment: if cvc and wvc are different.Then cvc is local variable.Any how it will lost when another controller push.You don't get that value.Can you specify what you want to achieve. Local variable scope with in the function only.

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko i have updated the non simplified version

Comment: @AJ112 Please read my comment.You have made the object local.And pushing another view.Where it scope lost.You don't get that value.

Comment: @iPhoneDev Can you tell how can i make it to work? Thanks!

Comment: @AJ112 check my answer below i think that work for you it's very small mistake you make.

Comment: @AJ112 I don't see that you're using Detail VC anywhere, you create it and then what?

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is called for a `UIViewController` instance when the `view` is required. Which happens when you either push it on navigation stack or present controller modally. I am not sure why the `viewDidLoad` method is getting called for `cvc` instance when it is neither being pushed or presented.

You can try a workaround if assigning property isn't working for you. Create a custom `init` method for `DetailViewController` like below,

```
- (id) initWithURLString:(NSString*) urlString {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.cUrlString = urlString;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Declare this method in your `DetailViewController.h`,

```
- (id) initWithURLString:(NSString*) urlString;
```

Then while creating the `cvc` instance use this init,

```
DetailViewController *cvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithURLString:entry.link];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i tried this code, Now inside the initWithUrlString, if i log the self.cUrlString, it shows the correct url that i want but if i log the self.cUrlString inside viewDidLoad, there it still shows null. Why is it so?

Comment: @AJ112 Are you resetting `cUrlString` anywhere else in the code? Because there is no reason for it to become `nil` otherwise.

Comment: i have rechecked it, its not getting reset anywhere or not assigned to nil anywhere. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you try to use your string property in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` instead of in `viewDidLoad` ? It would be better ...

It might be that you are creating view and its `viewDidLoad` method/message is called when you create your view controller or add it to the stack.

You can also use story boards:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:

Answer (score 0):

```
        DetailViewController *cvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        cvc.cUrlString = entry.link;
```

the above code you are creating new object of the DetailViewController..
either you have to present or push this to the navigation controller to display the same

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
```

now you will have your viewController with CUrlString...

Comment: @AJ112 you mean that you want to change the value of view controller which was already on the navigation controller stack?

Comment: Means wvc is an instance of another class where i am pushing some other data. and cvc is the instance of another class where i also WANT to push the string.

Comment: @AJ112
i believe cvc and wvc are Viewcontrollers...
pushing this means that you are displaying these view controllers ... so what you mean push simultaneously.....
i mean you got two view cvc and wvc... isnt.?

Comment: @AJ112
ok.. now you have two view of 'WebViewController' and'DetailsViewController' ... now when do you want to display these views ie, if you are pushing the control will go to the viewDidLoad of the the VC pushed...

Now you have implemented this on the cellclick of table row... ie do you want the ViewControllers displayed when cell is clicked? and how i mean there are two...so one after another?

Answer (score 0):

i think you did not set Table view delegate in where you are creating table view

```
  tableView.delegate = self;
  tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `DetailViewController.m` **initWithNibName** method alloc your string like do below

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
      cUrlString = [[NSString alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I think there is somting wrong with your code i tell you another way you go to this way ok  make a constant class in wich take an NSString *cUrlString; #import <constant.h> wher you need that string to use for example first of all import  in FirstViewController and simply put that code on your didSelectRowAtIndexPath cUrlString = entry.link; and after that in your detail view controller import constant class and use cUrlString where you want to use try it i m sure it work for you

Answer (score 0):

NSLog the string you pass on `viewDidAppear` not on `viewDidLoad`, the string is not yet initialized on load but it is on appear (which is called after interface was loaded).

I'm posting this as my personal experience and research.